# Want to Update existing .csv file in LoadRunner

Tags: csv, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

**I have a scenario of File upload CSV in Load Test using LoadRunner.**

I have 1 user to upload file CSV with unique data in each iteration (Multiple Iteration), But when user going to upload same file in 2nd iteration it is throwing error as: "data already exist" it is because user is uploading same file's content each time. so i want to update column data in csv before upload.
Lets say i have data in csv like this

ID,  Name,         Department
121, Mohd Sarfraz, CS
122, Mohd Sarfraz, CS

**So id should be unique each time before upload.**

**Issue: How to Update column "ID" in existing csv file using LoadRunner first and then upload the csv file.**

Comment: please detail what you have tried so far

Comment: I am new to this, looking for answer to achieve this scenario.

Comment: Please detail what you have tried and what your results have been.    LoadRunner is a C programming environment, what is your hypothesized path to open a file, modify a file, close a file, then upload a file?   How would you validate your hypothesis using both your skills as a tester and as a tool user?

Comment: @JamesPulley Thanks for your reply.
I have a scenario to upload csv files sequentially in 100 iterations with 1 user only, as per scenario, need to upload 100 csv file sequentially in 100 iterations with single user, there are 2 ways coming in my mind, first is create 100 files manually and upload them sequentially in 100 iterations. 2nd - create 1 csv file only and update existing data in csv and then upload csv file ( As exactly u mentioned -  what is your hypothesized path to open a file, modify a file, close a file, then upload a file)

Comment: fopen()...fclose().... are these familiar to you?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.